# Schur factorization to find Unitary matrix?

Tags: r, matlab, matrix

After performing the Schur factorization using function Schur in library 'Matrix', how do I find the associated unitary matrix in R?

I can do this in MATLAB with the function Schur (documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/schur.html)), however, the Schur package in R only provides the triangular in the Schur factorization = $$ U * T * U' $$

Comment: The Schur class appears to have a slot for `Q`, the 'Square _orthogonal_ "Matrix"' (from the docs). Thus I guess you would just do `Sch.A <- Schur(A); U <- Sch.A@Q`.

Comment: Thanks! Happy to award answer for this if you want to copy/paste your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the docs for the "Matrix" package, I noticed that the 'Schur' class has a slot for `Q`, which is the 'Square *orthogonal* "Matrix"' associated with the decomposition. So you want to do:

```
Sch.A <- Schur(A);
U <- Sch.A@Q
```

This is mildly confusing because they quote the decomposition as $A = Q^{\top} T Q$, which is perhaps why you missed it.